# Laravel 5.3 loading data from ajax (a lot of data)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Hello i making a administrator panel to control my vps, dedicated servers, so i have a lot of data f.e Cpu usage, memory usage, disk storage usage, load etc and i use to this progress bar like this:

```
<li class="content"> <span>Cpu usage </span>
    <div class="progress progress-mini progress-danger active progress-striped">
        <div style="width: 99%;" class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <span class="percent">87%</span>
    <div class="stat">Cores: 100</div>
</li>
```

and i want to load this with ajax(i know what to do this)
but

```
Route::get('/ajax/cpuUsage',function(){
    //mysql query here
    return response()->json('MyData');
});
```

but when i have 10 viewers on my page this route will be called ten times, and i have ten request per f.e 5sec is a small ammount but when i have 1k viewers is can be over kill. So i want to cache data but laravel cache min for 1minute, what should i do? sory for my english, but i think you can undestard what i say :)

Comment: This is just idea that somebody should confirm, but I think that nginx instead of apache should be helpful (I think you have apache). Another thing is to use node js... i doubt that PHP would fit here best

Comment: Caching doesn't make sense here because "usage" statistics like these are meant to be displayed in real time data.

Comment: yea but i want to cache for 5seconds, so i can call this real time data, i can't make 1 request per 1 user on page, what i can should do?

Comment: You should be using post, not get... because the get-urls will be too long and make your server puke.

Comment: And you could use `session` to store the data: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax like this:

```
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/cpuUsage',
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                // do some logic here...

            }
        });
    });
```

You probably should move your logic to fetch CPU usage data to a controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UsageController extends Controller
{




/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
      // logic here
    return response()->json($mydata);
    }

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{

}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

then have your routes/web.php route look like this:

```
Route::get('/ajax/cpuUsage', 'UsageController@index');
```

Comment: yes i know but when i call /ajax/cpuUsage, my function in route will make a query, so if i have on page f.e 1k vievers this function was called 1k times is correct? if is correct then is to many for my database;/

Comment: I don't think you will really need to worry about that. However you could Cache the query $users = DB::table('cpuUsage')->remember(3)->get();  That way your db should not get overwhelmed. I believe if you have a thousand users that your query will get ran once every 3 minutes or whatever you set it to. If they are constantly getting data from that route.

Comment: Ok i found i can put in cache remember float so i make:       
  $time = Cache::remember('key', 0.08, function(){
            return Carbon::now()->second;
        });
and this cache $time for 5sec so is good for me i think i will make this query with this :) but thanks for help :)